# What kind of IC component is this (JBN 5)? Photo

Tags: identification, components

I'm playing with an Electric Fence Tester, trying to understand the schematics. I can't identify this component, due to my poor knowledge in electronic.

[image]

The aim was to connect the 7 segment display to an Arduino and make a remote tester via Wifi&REST request to my PHP server...but iI would prefer to read directly an analog pin that give me back the tension, yet transformed and stabilized.

Now I have wrote this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff9Fac.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thank you in advance! (sorry for my english).

Comment: As the component is called "D4" on this PCB, chances are it's a diode or a couple of diodes in one package.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes Diode or thyristor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator but I don't understand how put the two diode in the scheme. Because the IC is also connected to the ground (battery minus, not the earth). Why?